# Other discord bot status

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So i want my bot status just to be `my prefix is !` or something like that. But the only options i could find is where it starts with `streaming, playing, watching, competing and listening`. Is there a way to do it without that?

Comment: asfar i know, you cant do it without type of presence, even if you tried to use it without type it'll use `PLAYING` as default type of presence

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `client.user.setPresence()`.

```js
 client.user.setPresence({
      status: 'online',
      activity: {
        type: 'WATCHING',
        name: 'my prefix is !'
      }
    })
  }
```